# Changing Input Value Based on Selection via jquery

Tags: jquery, input

I want to change an input value based off a user selection.

```
        <input type="number" class="minimum" name="minimum" />
                    <div>0</div>
                    <div onclick="update('minimum')">$50,000</div>
                    <div>$100,000</div>
                    <div>$250,000</div>
                    <div>$500,000</div>
                    <div>$1,000,000</div>
                    <div>$10,000,000</div>
```

Here I have an input named **minimum** where a user can select a value by clicking on the divs and the input value will change.

This function 'as is' will update the input value once the div is clicked.

```
        function update(field){
        $('input[name=minimum]').val('50000');
        
    }
```

What I want is for this to be flexible to use on all the divs.

> [name=minimum] where **minimum** is replaced by the **field** value being passed into the function.
>
> val('50000') where the **50000** is replaced by the value of the div firing the function.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why doesn't the function use the `field` argument?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your inline event handler and instead use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    $('input[name=minimum]').val( parseInt( $(this).text().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""), 10 ) )
  })
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lwbh388f/)**

This takes the text string and converts it into a number to use in the input. You also probably want to use a selector more specific than `$('div')` as that will target all the divs on your page.

Comment: You need to remove the `$` and `,` characters from the HTML before putting it into the value.

Answer (score 0):

A friend showed me what I was doing wrong. I was using a (.) vs. (+)

```
        function update(field){

        $('input[name=' + field + ']').val('50000');
        //alert (field);
    }
```

This now works.